# Is there a single variable I can use in mod_rewrite that is equivalent to %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file (not in a .htaccess file) and I was wondering if there was a variable I could use that represents the entire request; ie `DOCUMENT_ROOT` represents the "path/to/htdocs" and `REQUEST_FILENAME` represents the "/path/to/file.php". Is there a single Apache variable that represents both of these together, like "path/to/htdocs/path/to/file.php" ?

The reason I'm asking is that in my rewrite directives, this doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

but this does:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

the weird thing is, all of the tutorials I've seen use the first format, but that didn't work for me and I came up with the second format on my own-- and I've never seen the second format being used in any tutorials. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm writing in httpd.conf instead of a .htaccess document?

When I output the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} variable, it does not include the document root.

Answer (score 1):

`%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is not **website.com**, it's the local path on the filesystem that is associated with the site's [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive. For example: `/var/www/localhost/htdocs`

If you want **website.com**, then you either want `%{SERVER_NAME}` (defined by the [UserCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) directive) or `%{HTTP_HOST}` which is defined by the **Host:** request header.

Additionally, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` *includes* the document root, it's more or less the equivalent of: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}`. So given the above example of the document root, and a request URI of `/images/title.png`, then the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` would be `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/images/title.png`

If what you're looking for is: **website.com/path/to/file.php**, then, no. There's not a single variable that puts this together for you. You either want:

```
%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or

```
%{SERVERNAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Ah sorry about the confusion about DOCUMENT_ROOT. The thing is, in my mod_rewrite directives, when I'm using a RewriteCond and I have to check if a file exists, it doesn't work when I just use %{REQUEST_FILE} but it works when I use %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILE}. Why is this the case?

Comment: When I output the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} variable, it does not include the document root.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have to do with the fact that I'm writing in httpd.conf instead of a .htaccess document?

Yes. From the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> `REQUEST_FILENAME`
>   The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time `REQUEST_FILENAME` is referenced. Otherwise, such as **when used in virtual host context, the same value as `REQUEST_URI`.**

And `REQUEST_URI` is the "path component of the requested URI, such as `/index.html`".

> the weird thing is, all of the tutorials I've seen use the first format

Because most of the tutorials are written with respect to a .htaccess (or `<Directory>`) context.

> If used in per-server context (i.e., before the request is mapped to the filesystem) `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` cannot contain the full local filesystem path since the path is unknown at this stage of processing. Both variables will initially contain the value of `REQUEST_URI` in that case. **In order to obtain the full local filesystem path of the request in per-server context, use an URL-based look-ahead `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` to determine the final value of `REQUEST_FILENAME`.**